# how to clear our application history when we navigate to one of our page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We have implemented our application navigation using react-router.

Ex: If we are having 3 pages page1,page2,page3 in our application how can we reset our application navigation history when go back to page1 from any other page.

page1->page2->page3->page1.(history should be clear so browser front and back navigation buttons are removed)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to clear browser history directly from the app so you can't really remove browser back and forward buttons.

Although in memory history of react router is mutable.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/567#issuecomment-386323573